# Sending Request body for GET method in AXIOS throws error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application where I am changing POST method to GET with the request body as it is. It works fine with POST request however when I change the method to GET, it gives me error-

```
message: "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public
```

My Front End Code-

```
export const setData = (getData)  => dispatch => {
    axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/api',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: getData
      })
      .then (response => {
      dispatch({
        type: API_DATA, 
        payload: response.data
      })
      dispatch({
        type: SET_SEARCH_LOADER, 
        payload: false
      })
      })
      .catch(function(error) {       
      })
}
```

Can someone let me know what I am missing here. As per my understanding, http allows to have a request body for GET method.

Comment: Axios GET request on Browser uses XMLHttpRequest which doesn't support request body and hence you face this issue. Check [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/462#issuecomment-366377629) on github for more details

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> As per my understanding, http allows to have a request body for GET method.

While this is technically true (although it may be more accurate to say that it just doesn't explicitly disallow it), it's a very odd thing to do, and most systems do not expect GET requests to have bodies.

Consequently, plenty of libraries will not handle this.

The [documentation for Axois](https://github.com/axios/axios) says:

> ```
>   // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
>   // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
> ```

Under the hood, if you run Axios client side in a web browser, it will use XMLHttpRequest. If you look at [the specification for that](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method) it says:

> `client . send([body = null])`
>
> Initiates the request. The body argument provides the request body, if any, and is **ignored if the request method is GET** or HEAD.

Comment: my getData is an emptyObject here which I am trying to send. Will this not work?

Comment: @techiequestie — No, it won't. The browser will ignore whatever you try to set as the request body and send the GET request without one.

Comment: So how should I handle it? Do I need to add any param to the request?

Comment: Either the request *should* be a POST request or the server should *not* expect a request body on a GET request. I have no idea what the request is requesting, so I can't say which of those is the right approach.

Comment: I have another api where from backend, they have appended the data as a parameter in the api, so then it works. But for this api, its not there so, I am trying to figure out if that is a must to have in backend or is there any way I can handle this through UI.

Comment: @techiequestie — As I said in the answer, you *can't* send a GET request with a body from the browser.

Comment: Thank you @Quentin so much! You just saved me from two hours of suffering to find the error in my app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send parameters with get request in axios, you should send parameters as `params`.

If you want to set `"Content-type":"application/json"` and send params with get request, you should also send an empty `data` object.

For example:

```js
const AUTH_TOKEN = 'Bearer token'
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': AUTH_TOKEN,
    },
    data: {},
    params: {
        "post_id": 1
    }
}
axios.get("http://localhost/api/v1/posts/", config)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not axios, the error origniates from the java backend you're talking to. The public field in your request body is missing.

If you just want to send the data as parameters (which would be odd), pass it using `params` instead of `data` (as shown here: https://github.com/axios/axios#example).

I personally don't think your API should support GET with a request body (talk to the devs and ask for documentation).

Comment: The OP is asking why the request body is missing (which **is** Axios)

Comment: I did not get it. Have I missed anything here?

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you're right, I got the question wrong. I amended my answer.