# axios get request with body and header

Tags: javascript, api, axios, get

how can I something like this, sending body params and header with Authorization token into this

[image]

```
const searchByDate = async ({ date1, date2 }) => {
  const tokenApp = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  const { data: res } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/search`, {
    data: { date1: date1, date2: date2 },
    headers: { Authorization: `${tokenApp}` },
  });
  return res;
};
```

so far it is throwing me an error **Required request body is missing**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending Request body for GET method in AXIOS throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54005520/sending-request-body-for-get-method-in-axios-throws-error)

Answer (score 5):

In general there is no point in a `body` for GET requests, so axios does not support it.

If you read the [axios config documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config), you will find

> // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
> // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE , and 'PATCH'

You can read more at [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) for the reasons.

---

If you want to send data in a GET request use the `params` property

> // `params` are the URL parameters to be sent with the request
> // Must be a plain object or a URLSearchParams object

Answer (score 0):

There is no field related to body in get method in axios you can transfer data by get the data in query in URL
like this:

```
const searchByDate = async ({ date1, date2 }) => {
  const data = { date1: date1, date2: date2 }
  const tokenApp = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  const { data: res } = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/search?data=${JSON.stringify(data)}`, {
    headers: { Authorization: `${tokenApp}` },
  });
  return res;
};
```

in backend to convert the data from string to original data types just wrap the data in

```
JSON.parse(data)
```