# req.body is missing from axios request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios, request

Here is the request that makes the req.body empty

```
const getLatest = async (limit) => (await axios({method: "GET", 
                                                url: `/posts/latest`,
                                                data: {limit: limit},})).data;
```

What is the problem here.

Comment: GET requests don't have any body semantics, that should probably be a query parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [axios get request with body and header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70445278/axios-get-request-with-body-and-header)